# What does "clutch grabs hard" mean?

Tags: honda, clutch, manual-transmission, s2000

I recently had an engine swap done and will pick it up soon. Mechanic swapped in a 6 puck competition clutch as well. Combined with a very light flywheel(same weight as I'm used to driving, 8 lb), it's well known on my car (Honda S2000) to be difficult to engage 1st gear, needs to be released slower, and generally requires more precision to make shifts.

What exactly does this phrase mean in terms of adjusting my driving style on manuals? Obviously the flywheel being lighter means faster revs.

Comment: I recently read up on the differences in clutch materials. If this is going to be your daily driver you might not like new driving style of the competition clutch. Some things are best for track use only

Answer (score 7):

It's the difference between where the clutch grabs and releases. It means that area between the two is very small (relative to clutch pedal travel). You will find there won't be a lot a *smooth transition* as you release the pedal. It will just *grab*. It will take some muscle memory recalibration to find the feathering point of your clutch consistently.

Something to remember with a new clutch and flywheel ... it needs to be broke in. Usually this takes about a 1000 miles. You don't want to overheat it during this time (no rodding your little S2000). If you do, you'll find you'll end up with a lot of chidder (vibration as you engage your clutch), which will make it doubly hard to engage your clutch. Be easy on your clutch during the break-in period. City driving is better for the break-in period, as highway driving won't get the wear on it you need.

Answer (score 4):

This style of clutch is harder to 'ride.'  You will have a harder time finding that sweet spot.  Combined with the lightweight flywheel, it will be rather difficult to take off.  You might run into situations where its stall or spin.

Once your moving, it should be the same.  You might want to get a short throw to take full advantage of the lightweight flywheel.

My experience is not s2000 specific.  I had a dodge spirit (FWD) with a v6, lightweight flywheel, and a Kevlar clutch.

Comment: Luckily s2000 has very short throw